# A function that confuses, does not do what it says it does

Tags: python

In the operator module, there is a method that is called `isub`, which takes two parameters, and dividing the first parameter in the second one.

Visual Studio Code says it does this: **Same as a -= b**, How?

In my example, I'm creating a variable called `a` and assigning 5 as its value, and then using the `isub` method, and saving the result into a variable, and then printing the result and `a`, but `a` is still 5, why?

```
import operator

a = 5
result = operator.isub(a, 4)
print(result) # 1
print(a) # 5
```

Comment: `int.__isub__` isn't defined; `a -= 5` when `a` is an `int` is exactly equal to `a = a - 5`; no in-place modification of `a` occurs.

Comment: @chepner But look in this function description, I'm using this function in VS-Code and it says that this is same as a-= b

Comment: The documentation words this poorly. It is not the same as `a -= b`; `a -= b` is *implemented* using `a.__isub__(b)` *if* `a.__isub__` exists. Or put another way, `a -= b` is exactly equal to `a = a - b` if `__isub__` does not exist, in which case `operator.isub` is equivalent to `operator.sub`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You chose a poor example. `int.__isub__` isn't defined, so `a -= 5` is exactly equal to `a = a - 5`, with no in-place modification of the original value.

Try with a set, which does implement `__isub__`.

```
>>> s = {1,2,3}
>>> operator.isub(s, {2})
>>> s
{1, 3}
```

`a -= b` is implemented as `a.__isub__(b)` *if* `a.__isub__` is defined. Otherwise, it is equivalent to `a = a - b`, which is implemented as `a = a.__sub__(b)`. Thus, `isub(a, b)` is the same as `a -= b`, but that *doesn't* mean `isub(a, b)` can or does modify `a` in-place.

Comment: Thank you, should I report this to VS-CODE ?

Comment: No, it's just displaying the documentation as provided by the `operator` module. I've reworded the explanation in the answer compared to my comment, as they are the "same", just not in the sense you were expecting.